# How to modify mailto link called by javascript to work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mailto

I have this JavaScript code (within a PHP page) that opens a new window to call a mailto link, then close the new window - this is done to allow the original window to continue it's process and opens an email in the users mail client.

```
<script language="javascript">
  var win;
  win = window.open("<?php echo $link; ?>" , "Email Window", "width=100,height=100");
  win.close();
</script>
```

This code works ok on Edge and Firefox, but not Chrome. I have googled about it - most people are saying about handlers, I have checked (the Chrome handlers), the only option is "allow sites to ask to become default handlers for protocols (recommended)".

Enabling or disabling does not fix the issue. I have tested this on a number of PCs.

Comment: Why not simply `<a href="mailto:email@domain.com">Your Email Link</a>` ?

Comment: Simply add `mailto:` before `$link` and js version will work in chrome, in mine works.

Comment: Thanks $link includes mailto: I don't want the user to click the link, i want the php script to call the link and open their mail client while continuing to process the rest of the php script. this is working within Firefox and edge, just not chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP script to call the link" - I don't see in this code any call to backend, there is only code, which on user side is simple JS? PHP is not runned on client side. If it's not all code, please provide the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to open a `mailto:` link in a browser window. Instead, create an `a` element, set its `href` and then click it programmatically

```js
let link = document.createElement('a')
// link.href = '<?= $link ?>'
link.href = 'mailto:johndoe@example.com'
link.click()
```